# How do I make a Nonetype into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This function returns Nonetype instead of a list and I have no idea why. How do I make this thing return a list?
Here is the code:

```
def fib_less_than(N):
    fibonacci_numbers = [1,1]
    fibonacci_n = fibonacci_numbers[-1] + fibonacci_numbers[-2]
    while fibonacci_n < N in range(2,N+5):
        fibonacci_n = fibonacci_numbers[-1] + fibonacci_numbers[-2]
        fibonacci_numbers.append(fibonacci_n)
    print(fibonacci_numbers[0:len(fibonacci_numbers)-1])

fib_less_than(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are returning nothing. So, you have to return the Fib. list, and do the printing outside the function:

```
def fib_less_than(N):
    fibonacci_numbers = [1,1]
    fibonacci_n = fibonacci_numbers[-1] + fibonacci_numbers[-2]
    while fibonacci_n < N in range(2,N+5):
        fibonacci_n = fibonacci_numbers[-1] + fibonacci_numbers[-2]
        fibonacci_numbers.append(fibonacci_n)
    return (fibonacci_numbers[0:len(fibonacci_numbers)-1])

print (fib_less_than(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `print` returns a `None` (it just displays stuff in the console). You need to `return` at the end of your function.